# Sending passport from Atlanta to NY for Canadian visitor visa

Tags: visas, canada

I applied for a Canadian visitor visa from Bangladesh, gave my biometrics and paid fees over there. But I live in Atlanta, USA now and want to submit my passport for the visa stamping. The Canadian consulate in ATL asked me to submit my passport in New York.

How do I do it by Mail? What kind of documents do I need to put it in? Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like a good question for the consulate

Comment: I'd definitely contact the consulate. At minimum you'll probably need a reference number or application number to quote along with the submitted passport, but you may well need either a form or at least a covering letter.